# How to pass password via Perl script

Tags: perl

I have a situation where in I am calling the below Perl script

```perl
if (param("lremail") && param("lot")) {
    my $address=param("lremailaddress");
    my $lot=param("lot");
    print a({-href=>"$dir/new.pl"},"Back to Top"),br;
    print "Request submitted for $address.",br;
    print "Lot $lot",br;
    print "You will receive an e-mail with a link to the data when the request is complete.";
    print end_html;
    system ("ssh SERVERNAME /test/abc.csh $lot $$ $address &");
    exit(1);
```

The above script does not run because when I execute the system is prompted for a password. Then I looked it up and found the below command..

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh SERVERNAME /test/abc.csh J213520 06 abc@gmail.com "ls -lh file"; expect "Password:"; send "PASSWORD\r"; interact'
```

The above command is executed successfully without any issue but from the command line only. When I incorporate the same(by replacing the system call) within the Perl script, it fails. How can I incorporate within the first script?

Comment: Set up key based ssh authentication.

Comment: @vidarlo is correct, but look at `sshpass` for an easier but less secure solution

Comment: imho, Off Topic: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Reiterating and adding to comments:

- Consider using a key-based authentication either with passphrase-less keys or with `ssh-agent` (e.g., using `ssh-keygen` generated/managed identities);
- Consider using `sshpass` or another `expect`-like external;
- Consider using the Perl `Expect` or an equivalent CPAN module; and/or,
- Consider using the Perl `Net::SSH` or an equivalent CPAN module.

Also, `system` can easily introduce remote code execution vulnerabilities, especially when using its `system LIST` syntax.

Comment: Hi Ahi324, Thank you for the reply.
As you can see my post, I have used the expect and is working fine from the command line, but when I incorporate the same in the above mentioned perl script, its not working.

I need to incorporate that line in the perl script.., how can I do that?